# Can package py-grpc-prometheus be used with the Python gRPC AsyncIO version?

Tags: python, asynchronous, grpc, prometheus

@lidi-zheng

We are converting existing Python gRPC services to the Python gRPC AsyncIO version (1.43.1). We currently use the `py-grpc-prometheus` package to collect/emit server and client metrics. This packages subclasses:

```
class PromServerInterceptor(grpc.ServerInterceptor):

class PromClientInterceptor(grpc.UnaryUnaryClientInterceptor,
                            grpc.UnaryStreamClientInterceptor,
                            grpc.StreamUnaryClientInterceptor,
                            grpc.StreamStreamClientInterceptor):
```

and uses a number of other gRPC package attributes, etc.

The question is, are the blocking and asyncio classes 'compatible' when used in this way? If not, any suggestions on alternative ways of collecting server/client request/response metrics?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

In py-grpc-prometheus - PromServerInterceptor is not compatible with the GRPC AsyncIO version.
This is the blueprint of the AsyncIO server interceptor: 
https://github.com/lchenn/py-grpc-prometheus/pull/32